# Return true or false in a list comprehension python

Tags: python

The goal is to write a function that takes in a list and returns whether the numbers in the list are even resulting in True or False. 
Ex. [1, 2, 3, 4] ---> [False, True, False, True]

I've written this portion of code:

```
def even_or_odd(t_f_list):
   return = [ x for x in t_f_list if x % 2 == 0]
```

I know this code would return [2, 4]. How would I make it so it instead returns a true and false like the above example?

Comment: `return  [x % 2 == 0 for x in t_f_list]`

Answer (score 16):

Instead of filtering by predicate, you should map it:

```
def even_or_odd(t_f_list):
   return [ x % 2 == 0 for x in t_f_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use lambda instead :

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
map(lambda x: x%2 == 0, l)
```

Comment: The OP wants a list comprehension (I suspect this is homework). Also, in Python 3, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator, not a list.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use bitwise `&` for that which is a bit faster then `%`:

```
t_f_list = [1,2,3,4]
res = [ not x&1 for x in t_f_list]
print(res)
[False, True, False, True]
```

**Timing**

```
In [72]: %timeit [not x&1 for x in t_f_list]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 795 ns per loop

In [73]: %timeit [ x % 2 == 0 for x in t_f_list]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 908 ns per loop

In [74]: %timeit list(map(lambda x: x%2 == 0, t_f_list))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 us per loop
```

*Note*: `list` for `map` is added to get a `list` of values because I'm using python 3.x

Comment: Interesting. I knew `&` was faster, but it's nice to see actual timings. But I suspect that the OP's teacher would prefer the answer to use `%`. :)

Comment: On my machine (2022 MacBook Pro M1 Max, Python 3.9.6), `%2` is faster than `&1` with your example. https://gist.github.com/strager/ab7d19388bf82f76e88a678ba1c20bb3

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to get both boolean and values:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
result = [x%2 == 0 for x in lst] # Returns boolean
result_1 = [x for x in lst if x%2 == 0] # Returns values
```